# Assert cell style onto text pasted into that cell

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting, copy-paste

I'm not quite sure how to word this so I couldn't find any answers to my question after some searching.

I am trying to copy and paste values into my Google sheet. These values are copied from another website which has a different font and font size than that which I have in my sheet. However, when these values are pasted they appear in the style that is on the website. Is there a way to pre-set a cell's style so that any value pasted into it conforms to the cell's preset style?

I am aware that I could set up multiple sheets, one as an input and another as an output, in order to solve this problem, although I'd rather not do this.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @user0 3rd column shows what happens when I copy, fourth shows what I want to happen when copied. This is a simplified version of my real sheet in order to make my point clearly. I want to see the cell colouring too. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mzx2xq2A7YBuR-CVkjpLUNEI1E06Ws8OoBCztlvdL9w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Sheets, pasted data auto-inherit default formatting of Google Sheets which is Arial 10px eg. it overrides all priorly set formattings. To counter this behavior there are three workarounds:

- double-click the cell and paste data

  [image: 0]

---

- paste data in fx bar instead of cell

  [image]

  ---
- paste it as is and copy the cell with the desired formatting (**A4**) and then select **A3** and press 
  <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd>

  [image: 0]